# Property expression of ExpressionStatement expected node to be of a type ["Expression"] but instead got "TSModuleBlock"

Tags: react-native, gradle, node-modules, gradlew

I am upgrading the dependencies of my react-native application from 0.53 to 0.59.
But I am facing the below error while trying to build it using `./gradlew assembleRelease.`

*@babel/template placeholder "$1": Property expression of ExpressionStatement expected node to be of a type ["Expression"] but instead got "TSModuleBlock".
@babel/template placeholder "$1": Property expression of ExpressionStatement expected node to be of a type ["Expression"] but instead got "TSModuleBlock"
at Object.validate (C:\vs-code-upgraded\node_modules@babel\types\lib\definitions\utils.js:132:11)
at validateField (C:\vs-code-upgraded\node_modules@babel\types\lib\validators\validate.js:24:9)
at validate (C:\vs-code-upgraded\node_modules@babel\types\lib\validators\validate.js:17:3)
at builder (C:\vs-code-upgraded\node_modules@babel\types\lib\builders\builder.js:38:27)
at Object.expressionStatement (C:\vs-code-upgraded\node_modules@babel\types\lib\builders\generated\index.js:316:31)
at applyReplacement (C:\vs-code-upgraded\node_modules@babel\template\lib\populate.js:86:27)*

I would like to know if there is possiblity to solve this build error.
thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm facing the precise same error... :/ And find it quite cryptic. Have you found the root cause and / or a fix?

Answer (score 1):

This might probably due to a namespace being exported which only contain interfaces/types (Not actual classes/functions/objects but type declarations).

A quick fix is to add `declare` to the exported namespace.

```js
export declare namespace SomeNameSpace
```

instead of

```js
export namespace SomeNameSpace
```